# replace angular expressions with static values in a string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In an angular controller I have:

```
var stringTemplate = "{{data.a}} - {{data.b}}";
var data = {a: "example1", b: "example2"};
```

Is there a way to replace the expressions in `stringTemplate` with static values from `data`. So in this case the result should be `"example1 - example2"`.

I need to store this in a database and use later when `data` is not available.

Values in `data` and `stringTemplate` will change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) syntax introduced in ES6.

```js
var data = {
    a: "example1",
    b: "example2"
};

var stringTemplate = `${data.a} - ${data.b}`;

console.log(stringTemplate);
```

---

**ES5:** Using Regex

```js
var data = {
    a: "example1",
    b: "example2"
};

var stringTemplate = "{{data.a}} - {{data.b}}";

stringTemplate = stringTemplate.replace(/\{{(.*?)}}/g, function($0, $1) {
    return data[$1.split('.')[1]] || $0;
});

console.log(stringTemplate);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, haven't come across Template Literals before, will give it a go.